# Set default Desktop resolution when no monitor

Tags: 12.04, xorg, resolution, vnc

**Background :**

I am using a `Ubuntu 12.04` with `X11VNC` server. Normally I do not connect the monitor to this computer. So it has some resolution issue. After few days of research I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/100741/214930) and it works fine. (paste following code in terminal)

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
       Identifier      "Default Device"
       Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier    "Default Screen"
   Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
   Device        "Default Device"
   SubSection "Display"
       Depth    24
       Virtual 1280 720
   EndSubSection
EndSection
EOF
sudo chmod 644 /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

**Problem:**

Now it's working properly when I access via `VNC` , but when I connect a monitor to that machine sometimes it goes to resolution(640*480).

I need to access this machine with and without a monitor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 - Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/ubuntu-14-04-add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)